Find nth bit index efficiently
Given a bit mask, I'd like to find the index of the nth 1 bit. For example with mask 00001001 and number 1 would return index 3. Same mask with number 0 would return 0. I need to do this as efficiently as possible. The best I came up with is this:
    while (mask) {
        int i = __builtin_ctz(mask);  // Find the index of the lowest set bit
        if (count == idx_num) {
            return i;
        }
        count++;
        mask &= (mask - 1);  // Clear the lowest set bit
    }

Is there any way to make this more efficient? I do not like the while and if-statement, which mainly cause the inefficiency. It'd be best to have it retrieved immediately but not sure if that's possible or if there are any builtin GCC functions that could be further capitalized on.
Would appreciate any help, thank you!
I've tried the above while loop but it doesn't seem to suffice.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7669057/find-nth-set-bit-in-an-int

This is not the same question at all and I'm not using x86-64 architechture.

Architecture you are using plays important role for optimizations. Please [edit] your question and include target architecture.

It's unclear what the types of variables are here, and what maximum values are. It makes a quite a bit difference if you are using 8-bit or 64-bit types, for example.

Problems like these are usually best solved by utilising somewhat exotic hardware instructions like popcount, pdep etc. but you haven't clarified what input bit width you're wanting or what hardware you're using. There are some good answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7669057/find-nth-set-bit-in-an-int?noredirect=1&lq=1

@Dan, What is the largest value of mask? 255?

Some of the answers in the linked question don't apply if you're not on x86-64, but I still don't see any fundamental difference between this question and the linked question. What's different? If it's the same, it's a fairly well known problem (because the rank-select succinct datastructure has the same problem) with also various portable solutions.

You could use this simpler version:
int get_nth_bit_index(unsigned mask, unsigned idx_num) {
    while (idx_num--) {
        mask &= (mask - 1);  // Clear the lowest set bit
    }
    return mask ? __builtin_ctz(mask) : 0;
}

Or to minimize jumps, this unrolled version:
int get_nth_bit_index(unsigned mask, unsigned idx_num) {
    switch (idx_num) {
      default: while (idx_num --> 9) mask &= mask - 1;
              mask &= mask - 1;
      case 8: mask &= mask - 1;
      case 7: mask &= mask - 1;
      case 6: mask &= mask - 1;
      case 5: mask &= mask - 1;
      case 4: mask &= mask - 1;
      case 3: mask &= mask - 1;
      case 2: mask &= mask - 1;
      case 1: mask &= mask - 1;
      case 0: break;
    }
    return mask ? __builtin_ctz(mask) : 0;
}

If mask is only 8 bits, you could use a lookup table, and with some effort, this lookup table can be used for larger mask types.
Here is a branchless version for 32-bit values using 2304 bytes of lookup tables. These tables must be initialized separately either at program startup time or at build time using a script:
#include <stdint.h>

enum { TABLE_BITS = 8, TABLE_LEN = 256, TABLE_MASK = 255 };

unsigned char bit_count[TABLE_LEN];
unsigned char nth_bit[TABLE_BITS][TABLE_LEN];

void initialize_nth_bit_tables(void) {
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < TABLE_LEN; i++) {
        unsigned count = 0;
        for (unsigned n = i; n; count++)
            n &= n - 1;
        bit_count[i] = count;
    }
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < TABLE_BITS; i++) {
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < TABLE_LEN; j++) {
            unsigned mask = j;
            for (unsigned idx = i; idx; idx--) {
                mask &= mask - 1;
            }
            nth_bit[i][j] = mask ? __builtin_ctz(mask) : 0;
        }
    }
}

unsigned get_nth_bit_index32(uint32_t mask, unsigned idx) {
    unsigned pos = 0, test;
    test = idx >= bit_count[m & TABLE_MASK];
    idx -= bit_count[mask & TABLE_MASK] * test;
    pos += TABLE_BITS * test;
    mask >>= TABLE_BITS * test;
    test = idx >= bit_count[m & TABLE_MASK];
    idx -= bit_count[mask & TABLE_MASK] * test;
    pos += TABLE_BITS * test;
    mask >>= TABLE_BITS * test;
    test = idx >= bit_count[m & TABLE_MASK];
    idx -= bit_count[mask & TABLE_MASK] * test;
    pos += TABLE_BITS * test;
    mask >>= TABLE_BITS * test;
    test = idx < TABLE_BITS;
    return pos + nth_bit[idx * test][mask & TABLE_MASK];
}


It still uses while, and if-statement.

@Dan: I'm afraid there is no magical solution to avoid those

I think lookup tables can avoid these.

You can avoid looping to discard set bits one-by-one, as shown for example Matters Computational section 1.10 "Index of the i-th set bit". (there are still ifs in that algorithm however)

@Dan: you are right, both if and while statements can be avoided using lookup tables. Yet you should run benchmarks to check if this approach is worth it.

@Dan: you can accept the answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.
